# Not getting the id in where clause - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get the record with special id and i have this in my method :

```
public function addedMark()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $subject = ClassSubject::where('teacher_id', $user->id)->pluck('id','subject_id');

    return view('educator.account.marks', [
        'user' => $user,
        'marks' => StudentMark::where('subject_id', $subject)->get()
    ]);
}
```

When i do `dd(ClassSubject::where('teacher_id', $user->id)->pluck('id','subject_id'));` i see that I'm getting the information that i need, but when i do `dd(StudentMark::where('subject_id', $subject)->get());` it returns an empty array.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to (whereIn)

```
 'marks' => StudentMark::whereIn('subject_id', $subject)->get()
```

and let see what hapens

Comment: that gets me only id1 , i need id 1 and id 2

Answer (score 1):

In `$subject`you have `id` and `subject_id`. You might wanna just take `subject_id`.

So change this: `StudentMark::where('subject_id', $subject)->get()`

to

`StudentMark::where('subject_id', $subject[1])->get()`

Comment: Try with `$subject->subject_id` or `$subject['subject_id]`. I've on mobile, so I didn't test this.

Comment: Both not working. I'm getting **Undefined property**

Comment: what do you get when you `dd($subject)`?

Comment: `Collection {#295 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    1 => 1
    2 => 7
  ]
}`

Comment: So, yeah, its an array. Try with the `$subject[1]`

Comment: yes but that get me only 1, i need 1 and 2 (everything from the array)

Comment: `ClassSubject::where('teacher_id', $user->id)->pluck('id','subject_id');` This would return only two values. The `id` and the `subject_id`. So when you are calling this, `StudentMark::where('subject_id', $subject)->get()` you should only use the `subject_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104918/discussion-between-yoanna-murdjeva-and-jilson-thomas).